# create individual buffers from vector points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, iterator

I am using QGIS and the python console to achieve the following: my problem is simple in that all I want to do is to create individual buffer shapefiles for each vector point.

The code I am using produces one shapefile with all the buffers in the that one file. What I'd like it to do is: for 5 points in the vector file I want 5 individual buffers.

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer 
import processing

mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()

QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, "path\to\output\output.shp", 50000, False, False, -1)
```

I understand that this might be achievable using a for loop so that would require a small change like so

```
for feature in layer:
    QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, "path\to\output\output.shp", 50000, False, False, -1)
```

but this produces the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/lazarusa/appdata/local/temp/tmprs5egx.py", line 9, in <module>
    for feature in layer:
TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I discovered another way to achieve this using the modeller tool in QGIS. simply clicking the "iterate over this layer" button and it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be iterable you need to select each feature and create an output file separately. So, you also need to have 'True' the fourth parameter in 'buffer' method of **QgsGeometryAnalyzer**. Next code works perfectly in my system.

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer 
import processing

mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()

for i in range(5):
    layer.select(i)
    my_path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/output" + str(i) + ".shp"

    QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, 
                                 my_path, 
                                 5000, 
                                 True, 
                                 False, 
                                 -1)

    layer.deselect(i)
```

I tried out with this shapefile for creating individual buffer shapefiles for five vector point features:

[image]

After running the above code at the Python Console of QGIS, I loaded the 5 resulting shapefiles at the Map Canvas:

[image]

It works as expected.

Comment: yup this works amazingly well. but if I didnt know the number of points I want and simply want every point to be buffered that would require a feature count type function prior to the for loop am I correct? and that value to be stored in a variable like i?

Comment: Yes. You can substitute 5 for n; where `n = layer.featureCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need change layer for layer.getFeatures().

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer 
import processing

mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()

feat = QgsFeature()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, "path\to\output\output.shp",50000, False, False, -1)
```

Comment: Please, read the output of **help(QgsGeometryAnalyzer.buffer)**: `buffer(...)
    QgsGeometryAnalyzer.buffer(QgsVectorLayer, QString, float, bool onlySelectedFeatures=False, bool dissolve=False, int bufferDistanceField=-1, QProgressDialog p=None) -> bool`

Comment: Tried this, it produces 1 buffer instead of 5 (or however many points I would have)

Comment: Produce 1 buffer for each feature!but the result is only 1 shapefile.